# Work around twitter rate limit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have created a web application which needs to make around 20000 calls per hour to twitter.
Current rate limit seems to be a problem as it allows only 450 call per application authentication.
Can i save oauth credentials of the user logged in to my web app via twitter in database and randomnly use the credentials to make calls on individual user ouath(150 calls/hour for ouath)  .
This will improve my calls to number of users logged into my app * 150 per hour + application authentication *450 per hour...Can i do this ...Is IP monitored for rate limit as well ?
How do companies use twitter nowadays with rate limit?

Answer (score 0):

> Can i save oauth credentials of the user logged in to my web app via twitter in database and randomnly use the credentials to make calls on individual user ouath(150 calls/hour for ouath)

You can, and Twitter will block your application and likely your IPs as well.

If your applications to make more calls than the REST API allows, then you need to look into the Streaming API.  Start here:
[Streaming API Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming)